# AutoMapper - list of ints to list of objects

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

**Movie entity**

```
    public class Movie
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public Director Director { get; set; }
        public int DirectorId { get; set; }
        public List<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

**CreateMovieM dto**

```
    public class CreateMovieM
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int DirectorId { get; set; }
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public string PublishDate { get; set; }
        public List<int> ActorsIds { get; set; }
    }
```

**Mapping Profile**

```
CreateMap<int, Actor>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));

CreateMap<CreateMovieM, Movie>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.Actors, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ActorsIds));
```

**Create Command**

```
public class CreateMovieCommand
    {
        private readonly IMovieStoreDbContext _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private CreateMovieM _Model { get; set; }
        public CreateMovieCommand(IMovieStoreDbContext context, IMapper mapper, CreateMovieM model)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _Model = model;
        }

        public void Handle()
        {
            var movie = _context.Movies.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == _Model.Name);
            if (movie is not null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Movie already exists");

            movie = _mapper.Map<Movie>(_Model);

            _context.Movies.Add(movie);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

**And this is data generator**

```
public class DataGenerator
    {
        public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider services)
        {
            using var context = new MovieStoreDbContext(
            services.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<MovieStoreDbContext>>());

            var a1 = new Actor { Id = 1, Name = "Kemal", Surname = "Sunal" };
            var a2 = new Actor { Id = 2, Name = "Peri", Surname = "Baumeister" };
            var a3 = new Actor { Id = 3, Name = "Daniel", Surname = "Radcliffe" };

            var m1 = new Movie { Name = "Blood Red Sky", GenreId = 1, DirectorId = 2, Price = 10, PublishDate = new DateTime(1999, 5, 19), Actors = new List<Actor> { a2 } };
            var m2 = new Movie { Name = "Harry Potter", GenreId = 2, DirectorId = 3, Price = 15, PublishDate = new DateTime(1999, 5, 19), Actors = new List<Actor> { a3 } };
            var m3 = new Movie { Name = "Hababam Sinifi", GenreId = 3, DirectorId = 1, Price = 20, PublishDate = new DateTime(1999, 5, 19), Actors = new List<Actor> { a1 } };

            context.Movies.AddRange(
                new Movie { Id = 1, Name = "Blood Red Sky", GenreId = 1, DirectorId = 2, Price = 10, PublishDate = new DateTime(1999, 5, 19), Actors = new List<Actor> { a2 } },
                new Movie { Id = 2, Name = "Harry Potter", GenreId = 2, DirectorId = 3, Price = 15, PublishDate = new DateTime(1999, 5, 19), Actors = new List<Actor> { a3 } },
                new Movie { Id = 3, Name = "Hababam Sinifi", GenreId = 3, DirectorId = 1, Price = 20, PublishDate = new DateTime(1999, 5, 19), Actors = new List<Actor> { a1 }, }
                );

            context.Genres.AddRange(
                new Genre { Id = 1, Name = "Action" },
                new Genre { Id = 2, Name = "Science Fiction" },
                new Genre { Id = 3, Name = "Comedy" }
                );

            context.Directors.AddRange(
                new Director { Id = 1, Name = "Ertem", Surname = "Egilmez" },
                new Director { Id = 2, Name = "Peter", Surname = "Thorwarth" },
                new Director { Id = 3, Name = "Chris", Surname = "Columbus" }
               );

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

**Sample input**

```
{   
    "name": "string",
    "price": 0,   
    "directorId": 1,   
    "genreId": 1,   
    "publishDate": "2020.1.1",   
    "actorsIds": [
       1   
     ]
}
```

im trying to map list of integer ids to list of Actors and getting "An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 1" error when i input to actorsids 1 which is one of actors id.

So how should i configure automapper to do this ?

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also add the SQL statements of your database tables to your question. It looks like you are using `Add()` on nested entity classes which already exists in the database. Do not use `Add()` on entities which are already there. Depending on your code you might want to load the existing entity from the EF context or set only the ids.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu

https://github.com/sinanoral/MovieStoreWebApi this is the repo. You can test by using movie controller post method.

sample input 

`{
  "name": "string",
  "price": 0,
  "directorId": 1,
  "genreId": 1,
  "publishDate": "2020.1.1",
  "actorsIds": [
    1
  ]
}`

Comment: @GertArnold  https://github.com/sinanoral/MovieStoreWebApi this is repo

Comment: A Stack Overflow question should contain all info *in the question itself* that's required to answer it.

Comment: @GertArnold I edited the question. I think it's okay now

Comment: @GertArnold SaveChanges method throws the exception in db context

Comment: @GertArnold list of integers in my create movie dto i gave it in question and in sample input actorsids

Comment: OK, yes. Well, you're trying to re-insert Actor 1 because it's also marked as `Added`.

Comment: @GertArnold yes that's what the error message says but i dont want to re-insert it i just want to map it by matching id

Comment: This is a very common error when adding new records. Make sure that existing entities are attached as `Unchanged`.

Comment: @GertArnold thank you for your help and time. Problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (var actor in movie.Actors)
{
    _context.Entry(actor).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
}
```

I solved my problem by adding that code before SaveChanges() method thanks to @GertArnold